# load woocommerce category id in theme search page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, themes

How to load woocommerce category id in theme search page by my theme (for example Mustang Lite is my theme ) $cat_id=1242;  thets my code. how to detect a category id at som products

```
  global $woocommerce;
  global $wp_query;
  $cat_id=1242;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "woocommerce_termmeta";
  $query="SELECT meta_value FROM {$table_name} WHERE `meta_key`='thumbnail_id' and woocommerce_term_id ={$cat_id} LIMIT 0 , 30";
  $result =  $wpdb->get_results($query);

  foreach($result as $result1){
      $img_id= $result1->meta_value;
  }     

  echo '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url( $img_id ).'" alt="category image">';
```

Answer (score 0):

i get it work load category image at the theme search for example Mustang Lite confirm it if thet work for all another users

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                $thumb_size = ( ! function_exists( 'wma_amplifier' ) ) ? ( array( 100, 100 ) ) : ( 'admin-thumbnail' );

                $output .= '<a href="'.$urllink.'" title="' . esc_attr( get_the_title() ) . '">';
                $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), $thumb_size );
                $output .= '</a>';
            }else{
$terms = get_the_terms( $prod_id, 'product_cat' );
if($terms) {
    foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
        $cats_ids_array[$key] = $term->term_id;
           }
  global $woocommerce;
  global $wp_query;
  $cat_id=implode( ",", $cats_ids_array ); 
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "woocommerce_termmeta";
  $query="SELECT meta_value FROM {$table_name} WHERE `meta_key`='thumbnail_id' and woocommerce_term_id ={$cat_id} LIMIT 0 , 30";
  $result =  $wpdb->get_results($query);

  foreach($result as $result1){
      $img_id= $result1->meta_value;
         }     
            $output .= '<a href="'.$urllink.'" title="' . esc_attr( get_the_title() ) . '">';
            $output .= '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url( $img_id ).'" alt="Placeholder" width="300" class="woocommerce-placeholder wp-post-image" height="300">';
            $output .= '</a>';
     }
}
```